# Software for screen clippings to capture information

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote-2007

What are the alternatives to the [OneNote 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/HA102124721033.aspx) feature for doing screen clippings to capture information ?

Answer (score 3):

[Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) has a similar feature, and the nice thing about it over OneNote is that it syncs online and is cross-platform, so you can access your notes from any browser or rich clients on Mac and Windows.  Even has an iPhone client.

Comment: its much the same like Onenote...i'm looking for a script or something like that- a lighter alternative

Comment: Snagit (http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp) is a popular standalone alternative, but it costs money.

Answer (score 1):

[PixClip](http://www.pixclip.net) is a free and lightweight alternative to OneNote's screen capture feature, and works much the same.  Just like OneNote, you can assign a shortcut such as WinKey + S.

Comment: it looks good and free, let me try it out